# Google Apps Script How to Create First Run Tutorial

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps-script-api

I am creating a Google Spreadsheet tool (with Google Apps Script) for a client to help them streamline their processes. I would like to create an interactive tutorial to show them how to use this new tool. I envision callouts that pop up pointing to a cell and saying "Insert last name here", then when they click on the callout, it closes and the next callout indicates a pull down menu and tells them "Select the date from this menu"... This is a bit oversimplified, but the idea is to show them the workflow of the tool. I just need a bit of guidance to get started. **Is there a Google Apps service that can do this?** I know I can create a sidebar using the HTML service, and that can work, but I can't see how it could "point to" cells within the worksheet. I've done a lot of searching, but I just keep coming up with tutorials for learning Google Apps Script, instead of how to create an interactive tutorial for my Google App tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Sheets does not have any features that can support a "first run" interactive tutorial on the sheet elements themselves (at least not to my knowledge). You can however create a custom dialog (modal) via HtmlService and build out a tutorial composed of gifs using standard html/css/javascript. Alternatively you can embed a screen cap of how to use the tool as a youtube video in said modal.

Comment: If it doesn't exist, that explains why I couldn't find it. The custom dialog with gifs could work. Thanks Dimu.